# Change path svg color on hover from jstree

Tags: html, css, jstree

I have the following snippet :

```js
$('#myTree').jstree({
        'core' : {
            'data' : [
                {
                    "text" : "Root node",
                    "children" : [
                        {
                            "text" : "Child node 1",
                        },
                        { "text" : "Child node 2" }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
    "types" : {
      "default" : {
        "icon" : "https://svgshare.com/i/jkA.svg"
      },
      "demo" : {
        "icon" : "https://svgshare.com/i/jkA.svg"
      }
    },
    "plugins" : [ "types", "wholerow" ]
});
```

```css
.jstree_folderIcon:hover{
  /*fill: #ddecfa !important*/
    /*fill: #4c5773 !important*/
    color:red;
}
.jstree-node .jstree-icon.jstree-ocl {
  background-image: url('https://svgshare.com/i/jiz.svg');
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  background-position: center !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
.jstree-node.jstree-open > .jstree-icon.jstree-ocl {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
#test123:hover{
  color:red;
    fill: red
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>


<div id="myTree"></div>
```

SVG icon folder :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
  <path id="test123" fill="#ddecfa" class="jstree_folderIcon" d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h5l2 2h5a2 2 0 012 2v6a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z" />
</svg>
```

SVG icon chevron :

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
  <path id="test123456" class="jstree_chevronIcon" style="color:#ddecfa;" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
</svg>
```

Here is the expected result :
[image]

How can I change the color of the folder and arrow on hover ?
I try setting up a class on the svg path but the color doesn't change.

Comment: The only way your page stylesheet _can_ influence any elements inside an SVG, is if that SVG was embedded into the HTML _directly_. You can not do it for SVGs that are used as background image, or embedded via img/object/iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the background image, on hover and put `!important`, so that it overrides the inline styling of icon.

```
.jstree-wholerow-hovered ~ .jstree-anchor > .jstree-icon,
.jstree-wholerow-hovered + .jstree-icon {
    background-image:linear-gradient(red,blue) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to hover on .jstree-wholerow class

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer. See if it works.

Comment: Perfect, how can I do the same for the arrow ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
  <path id="test123" fill="CurrentColor" class="jstree_folderIcon" d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h5l2 2h5a2 2 0 012 2v6a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z" />
</svg>
```

---

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2">
  <path id="test123456" class="jstree_chevronIcon" fill="CurrentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9 5l7 7-7 7" />
</svg>
```

by putting CurrentColor as the fill value, the svg will get the `color` property's value.

for example:

```css
svg {
  width: 5rem;
  color: red
}

svg:hover {
  color: blue
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none">
  <path id="test123" fill="CurrentColor" class="jstree_folderIcon" d="M2 6a2 2 0 012-2h5l2 2h5a2 2 0 012 2v6a2 2 0 01-2 2H4a2 2 0 01-2-2V6z" />
</svg>
```

Now instead of putting the svg as a background or a source for an img element. you put it directly in your html like a normal element.

Comment: jsTree use it as background-image, can't change it

Comment: idk how jstree works cz i havent used it in my life but maybe you can put 2 different svgs with the colors you want and when you hover you just alternate between them.

Just a guess